# Change layout just for one cms page - for instance "customer-service"

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm using the pages that comes with the default instalation of magento on my web store. The customer want's to have diferent contents on right column of that pages. 
For instance, on "customer-service" page wants to have the top FAQ's but on "contacts" want to have the telephone and mail information.

How can I achive that? I been trying to change the 2columns-right layout, on the right column, to each page but I was unable to find a way to do that.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

In 'CMS > Pages' from the Magento back office, go into the 'Design' tab in each page you want to change and set the 'Layout' to '2 columns with rightbar'.

Then, you can use the `right.permanent.callout` block to call in what content you wish on various pages/page types as wanted.

For example, displaying an image in the right sidebar on contact page only:-

```
<contacts_index_index>
    <reference name="right">
        <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" before="cart_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
        <block type="core/template" name="right.permanent.callout" template="callouts/right_col.phtml">
            <action method="setImgSrc"><src>images/media/col_right_callout.jpg</src></action>
            <action method="setImgAlt" translate="alt" module="catalog"><alt>Keep your eyes open for our special Back to School items and save A LOT!</alt></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</contacts_index_index>
```

You can modify to change the page, page type, or template/block as you wish.